# Each header list inside horizontal list using Recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have Group list and each group have some members in horizontal list how do it using adapter inside horizontal recyclerview.....

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you've tried thus far?

Comment: https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-a-vertical-recyclerview/